# Why does call to exit function create a new basic block

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, clang

I have a function defined as:

```
int f_2() {
  rand();
  return 10;
}
```

clang breaks it up into 3 basic blocks. This is understandable.

however when I replace the call to rand() by exit(0), then it breaks it into 4 basic blocks.
Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) says that functions that cannot return can be at the end of a basic block.

How does clang know that exit() function does not return?
I am compiling my code with clang -c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clang` is a C compiler. It's permitted to take advantage of guarantees made by the language standard for standard library functions.

There may also be something in the particular implementation of `<stdlib.h>` that marks `exit()` as a function that doesn't return, perhaps using a language extension or the `_Noreturn` keyword added by the 2011 ISO C standard.

Another example of this: the call `sin(0.0)`, with `-O1` or higher, compiles to a literal `0.0`, because the compiler knows about the `sin` function. (Which means that a program that calls `sin(0.0)` needs to be linked with `-lm` only if you don't optimize it.)

This is all permitted because a program that defines its own (non-`static`) function with the same name as a standard library function has undefined behavior; the compiler needn't consider the possibility that a call to `exit` or `sin` does anything other than what the standard specifies for those functions.

Comment: yeah thats what I was wondering. What language extension it is or if it is hard coded into the code somewhere. Need to spend some time looking though. If you find out what precisely causes this then can you please update your answer?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga It's quite easy. Just open up /usr/include/stdlib.h. You will find something like this prototype `extern void exit (int __status) __THROW __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));` . The \_\_attribute\_\_ ((\_\_noreturn\_\_)) is a gcc extension, which many other compilers understand too. It could also be the compiler intristically knows how some of the standard functions work.

Comment: I added `__attribute__((__noreturn__))` to rand() function in /usr/include/stdlib.h. That makes 4 basic blocks with rand() function too.

Answer (score 2):

`clang` is a pretty smart beast. You'd be surprised by the amount of things it can figure out.

The `exit` function is standard, and is known not to return. The compiler takes advantage of this fact.